# Grouping similar items using hashmap

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I have a input like this

```
0    [0.327097, 0.326998, 0.0]
0    [1.056364, 0.601873, 0.0]
0    [1.273154, 1.656441, 0.0]
1    [1.48469, 0.095074, 0.0]
1    [1.061504, -0.768175, 1.0]
```

i need to sort them as

```
0 :  [ [0.327097, 0.326998, 0.0] ,[1.056364, 0.601873, 0.0], [1.273154, 1.656441, 0.0]]
1 :  [ [1.48469, 0.095074, 0.0], [1.061504, -0.768175, 1.0]]
```

I did like this ..

but i am not getting the same output.my output is getting repeated.

Can u pls help me out...

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> groupMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
                   String[] subparts = finalline.split("\\[");    

                  String groupKey;
                  String value;

                  if (subparts.length == 1) {                                 
                      groupKey = null;
                      value = subparts[0];
                  }
                  else    if (subparts.length == 2) {                         
                      groupKey = subparts[0];
                      value = subparts[1];
                  }
                      else {
                      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not parse string");
                  }

                  Collection<String> groupContents = groupMap.get(groupKey);     
                  if (groupContents == null) {                                    
                      groupMap.put(groupKey, groupContents = new ArrayList<String>());
                  }
                  groupContents.add(value);                                    

                }
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of the `groupMap` map is another collection, so you can iterate through that collection within the outer loop as given below

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> groupMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
for(String key : groupMap.keySet()){
    System.out.println("Key: " + key);
    Collection<String> values =  groupMap.get(key);
    for(String value : values){
        System.out.println("value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> groupMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
for (String s : groupMap.keySet()) {
   for (String s1 : groupMap.get(s)) {
       System.out.println(s1);
   }
}
```

A collection within a collection just means nested loops--just like with a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to loop over the entries in your `Map` is as follows:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> groupMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: "+entry.getKey());
    for (String val : values) {
        System.out.printlnln("Value: "+entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a [HashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html) from "Guava" instead.

It helps make it easy to handle a mapping from keys to multiple values and is a general way to associate keys with arbitrarily many values.

Here's an example.

```
Multimap<String, String> map = HashMultimap.create();
map.put("1", "a");
map.put("1", "b");

map.put("2", "c");
map.put("2", "d");
```

And now you can use the "values()" view to iterate over the values in the map.

```
for(String value : map.values()) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

This will give you

```
a
b 
c 
d
```

Or if you want the key along with the value, then you can use the "entries()" view.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entries()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

This will give you

```
Key: 1 Value : a
Key: 1 Value : b
Key: 2 Value : c
Key: 2 Value : d
```

And if you're looking for a plain old java simple solution

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
// ... Some code to put values in the map
for(String key : map.keySet()){
    System.out.println("\nKey: " + key);
    List<String> values = map.get(key);
    for(String value : values) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and most efficient way to iterate over a map's entries is:

```
Map<String, Collection<String>> map;
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print(entry.getKey()+":");
    for (String str : entry.getValue())
       System.out.println(str);
}
```

This code will produce the output you requested.

Note that at no point are the keys looked up. When you iterate over the entry set, you have direct access to both the (typed) key and (typed) value.